# Pygame parpadeo molesto

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, game

estoy haciendo una interfaz con *pygame*: graficar puntos que caen simultáneamente. En una función elijo la posición y un color aleatorio. Luego llamo esta función con multi-hilo.

Al tener varios puntos en la pantalla comienza un parpadeo; no es totalmente fluida la imagen.

```
funcion()
    speed = 1
    pos1 = 1
    for i in range(0,600):
        i = i + speed
        pygame.draw.circle(surface,color,(pos1,i), 50,0)
        pygame.display.update()
        surface.fill(black)
        if i == 700:
           draw = False
simplethread=threading.Thread(target=funcion)
simplethread.start()
```

Comment: Ya intentaste modificar los frame por segundos?, probaste a ejecutar sin el thread, solo dejando correr de forma normal?

Comment: Una advertencia (no se si será la causante de tu problema), PyGame como muchas bibliotecas gráficas no es threadsafe. En principio no debes dibujar desde otro hilo directamente jamás, esto debe hacerse solo desde el hilo principal. Python gracias al GIL  permite que generalmente no explote todo por los aires, pero podemos tener comportamientos bastante inesperados. Lo normal es comunicar los hilos con eventos y que sea el principal el que dibuje lo que el hilo hijo le manda procesado.

Answer (score 0):

tendrá que ver con el

```
funcion()
```

sin parámetro ya que la clase se puede moldear...según la arquitectura, recuerda:: funcion()=5%6%4%yWf*PI*sqr(2.1)//1

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).